# Static type of Future<T> in classes not working | Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, types, future, static-analysis

I want to make a Class in Dart with a static type of Future<T>.
Because I want to implement its Call-Function async with type T, so I can call it like this:

```
MyFunction<T> func = MyFunction<T>();
T var = await func();
```

I tried to define this Class in that way:

```
class MyClass<Future<T>> {
  
 Future<T> call() async {
  //return a Future<T>
 }

}
```

It gives me a compiler error:

`Expected to find '>'`

It seems like it works only with type `Future` and not `Future<foo>`

Why does this not work?
Is there another way to force the Type of the Class to be a Future of type T somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Future` cannot be part of your generic type. Instead just use `T` and return the `Future` parameterized with `T` in your function. Like this:

```
void main() async {
  Test t = Test<String>();
  t.setVal("Hello World");
  String val = await t.getFuture();
  print(val);
}

class Test<T> {
  T? val;
  
  void setVal(T val) {
    this.val = val;
  }
  
  Future<T> getFuture() {
    return Future.value(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out that I can define the return type of the Call-Function different from the static type of the class. So I can define `Future<T> call()` the same way as your Function `Future<T> getFuture()` even if i define it in `class Test<T>`.

Comment: The generic type of the class does not dictate every method's return type. You are still free to return whatever you wish.